# Why My C# Object not Moving in windows form graphics?

Tags: c#

Hello Friends I have java code below here
https://p5js.org/examples/arrays-array-objects.html
so i have modified this code to c# windows form application below

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Example1_3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        int unit = 50;
        int count;
        int wideCount;
        int highCount;
        MyModule[] defaultMyModuleBinding;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
            this.BackColor = Color.Black;
            this.Width = 720;
            this.Height = 360;

        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                defaultMyModuleBinding[i].update();
                defaultMyModuleBinding[i].draw(g);
            }
            g.Dispose();
        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = 0;
            wideCount = this.Width / unit;
            highCount = this.Height / unit;
            count = wideCount * highCount;

            defaultMyModuleBinding = new MyModule[count];

            for (int y = 0; y < highCount; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < wideCount; x++)
                {

                    defaultMyModuleBinding[index++] = new MyModule(x * unit, y * unit, unit / 2, unit / 2, NextFloat(0.8f, 0.05f), unit);
                }
            }
        }

        private float NextFloat(float min, float max)
        {
            System.Random random = new System.Random();
            double val = (random.NextDouble() * (max - min) + min);
            return (float)val;
        }
    }

    public class MyModule
    {
        //private data members
        private float xOff;
        private float yOff;
        private float x;
        private float y;
        private float unit;
        private float speed;
        private int xDir;
        private int yDir;


        //default constructor
        public MyModule(float Xoff, float Yoff, float X, float Y, float Speed, float Unit)
        {
            this.xOff = Xoff;
            this.yOff = Yoff;
            this.x = X;
            this.y = Y;
            this.unit = Speed;
            this.speed = Unit;
            this.xDir = 1;
            this.yDir = 1;
        }

        //method to print all details
        public void update()
        {
            this.x = this.x + this.speed * this.xDir;
            if (this.x >= this.unit || this.x <= 0)
            {
                this.xDir *= -1;
                this.x = this.x + 1 * this.xDir;
                this.y = this.y + 1 * this.yDir;
            }
            if (this.y >= this.unit || this.y <= 0)
            {
                this.yDir *= -1;
                this.y = this.y + 1 * this.yDir;
            }
        }

        public void draw(Graphics g)
        {
            Pen p = Pens.White;
            Brush b = Brushes.White;
            g.DrawEllipse(p, this.xOff + this.x, this.yOff + this.y, 6, 6);
            //g.FillEllipse(b, this.xOff + this.x, this.yOff + this.y, 6, 6);
        }
    }


}
```

But i got different result. Please give me point out where i created mistake to doesn't move my object?

Give me suggestion where i am doing wrong.

Comment: what result is `different result`?

Comment: It's not a game engine. Paint will be called when the window needs to be repainted. The easiest way to force this is to resize it or minimise it and then restore it. If you want to do it programmatically, you have to instruct it to refresh the form from a timer.

Comment: To add to the answer from @John, look into `Invalidate` and `Refresh`.  WinForms tries to paint as least often as possible.

Comment: If you want to make games in c# you would be far better using Unity. Windows forms us for what it says - forms. E.g. business applications, that kind of thing.